# Django's full_clean swallows the code kwarg to ValidationError. What to do about this?

Tags: django

For a long time I've called `full_clean` in `save` when I need to do some cross-field validation in `clean`:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    a_field = models.TextField()
    another_field = models.TextField()

    def clean(self):
        if 'condition one' in self.another_field:
            if 'condition two' in self.a_field:
                raise ValidationError('oops', code='condition_one_two_err')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What I noticed today is that this causes the `code` kwarg on ValidationError to get swallowed.

This is because in Django's [`full_clean` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.1/django/db/models/base.py#L1198) my `ValidationError` is caught and then the method [raises its own instance](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.1/django/db/models/base.py#L1232) without passing along the code attribute.

Is this a bug or is it intended behavior?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's intended behaviour, because the instance raised by `full_clean` has possibly collected multiple `ValidationError` instances raised over cleaning a handful of fields.  The error details are merged into one instance, so that when you submit a form you see all errors at once as opposed to having to resubmit data and correct form errors one-by-one.

Now, the `ValidationError` class only has one code attribute, so what should it do if multiple errors in the clean process each have mentioned different codes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of djnago Model's clean method source code:

```
try:
        self.clean()
    except ValidationError as e:
        errors = e.update_error_dict(errors)
if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```

You are right Django "eats" your code. I believe that you should call just a `self.clean()` method on object save. Why? You don't need to validate the uniqueness of instance data and you don't have any additional validators assigned to your fields.